# MySQL 5.x: equivalent of \s but for another connection?

Tags: mysql

When you use the mysql-client and run `\s` it shows you the status of the current user.  I'm testing out SSL connection(s) and I want to be able to find out the SSL status, etc. of another connection id.  `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows all the sessions, but doesn't display any SSL session information (cipher, etc.) like `\s` does for the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm asking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

SSL connection status is a session variable and I don't think you can reference those from other sessions.

You can find out if the server supports it:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';
```